# SQL Moving SUBSTRING select into INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have this query

```
SELECT ID,

    SUBSTRING(( SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CONVERT(varchar(10), CC.CompanyId)  
            FROM Company CC 
            INNER JOIN CompanyProducts  NP2 
            ON CC.CompanyId = NP2.CompanyId 
            WHERE NP.CompanyProducts Id = NP2.PrimaryCompanyProducts Id 
                AND NP2.CompanyProducts Id <> NP2.CompanyProducts Id 
            FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) AS CompanyIdList

FROM CompanyProducts NP
```

I would like to add the SELECT into an INNER JOIN which I will add to my select to check if the return is null or zero

it will be something like this

```
SELECT ID,

    SUBSTRING(( SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CONVERT(varchar(10), CC.CompanyId)  
            FROM Company CC 
            INNER JOIN CompanyProducts  NP2 
            ON CC.CompanyId = NP2.CompanyId 
            WHERE NP.CompanyProducts Id = NP2.PrimaryCompanyProducts Id 
                AND NP2.CompanyProducts Id <> NP2.CompanyProducts Id 
            FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) AS CompanyIdList,

    CompanyIdCount --this will be null or a real value      

FROM cmp.CompanyProducts NP

INNER JOIN(SELECT DISTINCT A.CompanyProductsId,

            (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CONVERT(varchar(10), CC.CompanyId)  
                 FROM Company CC 
                 INNER JOIN CompanyProducts  NP2 
                ON CC.CompanyId = NP2.CompanyId 
                 WHERE NP.CompanyProducts Id = NP2.PrimaryCompanyProducts Id 
                AND NP2.CompanyProducts Id <> NP2.CompanyProducts Id ) AS CompanyIdCount


        FROM cmp.CompanyProducts  A
       )E ON NP.CompanyNotificationId =  E.CompanyNotificationId
```

How can I get the inner JOIN to incident null for no records or 1 record or more? THanks

Comment: This is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using? "SQL" is a standard for a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Huh? Could you show us structures and example  result sets. @a_horse_with_no_name is right that SQL is invalid and as is the question is highly unlikely to get answered.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ... I believe the lower is psuedo code as OP claims *something like this*. But top may be current working code.